# getApplicationContext() returns null in a Service

Tags: android, service, android-context

I have a Service in it's own process, I've declared it in manifest like that:

```
   <service
        android:name="com.discountscatcher.util.PointService"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:process=":pointservice" >
    </service>
```

But `onStartCommand` I was trying to get an `ApplicationContext`, but it always returns null, what I can forget?

```
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

and I starting it like that:

```
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PointService.class));
```

in `Myactivity OnCreate`

any ideas?

Comment: I think what you need is Interprocess communication

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#IPC

Comment: A service is a Context, why do you need the application context?

Comment: @FunkTheMonk how i can get an application resources like strings, drawables etc?

Comment: @whizzzkey the same as you would in an Activity / Application - Service extends from Context - you can just call getString(), getResources().getDrawable() etc

Comment: @FunkTheMonk no man, it seems to be some differs between application context and service context when service has started as separate process and when i call getString() or any other resource it always returns me null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are running your `Service` in a different process so it has no communication with the Actual Application process..

Try to remove this line from your service

```
android:process=":pointservice"
```

After your application is finished Application context is becomes null. At most situations there is no need to run the service in a different process. Also it is not recommended.

For more information check here

1. [Service in another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658511/android-how-to-decide-whether-to-run-a-service-in-a-separate-process)
2. [service reference Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458300/how-to-create-an-android-activity-and-service-that-use-separate-processes)

Comment: Please tell me for what reasons i should start a service in another process?