# context.getApplicationContext() returns null in a Service

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-context

I create a IabHelper object in a Service, but sometimes it throws a NullPointerException, that I found out is due to `context.getApplicationContext()` that sometimes return `null` int the constructor of IabHelper.

In other words, `context.getApplicationContext()` sometimes returns `null`, but I cannot understand why.

The IabHelper object is the one described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html), slightly modified.

Here's what I do: in the onCreate() method of the Service, construct an IabHelper object:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    IabHelper helper;
    ...

    public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      ...
      helper = new IabHelper(this);
      ...
    }
}
```

Here `this` should not be null. The IabHelper object is something like this:

```
public class IabHelper {
  Context context;

  public IabHelper(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx.getApplicationContext();
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, as explained above, when I call `context.getPackageName()` or any other method, a NullPointerException is thorwn. This happened only 7 times in a month over about 50 users (in fact I was not able to reproduce it).

The only similar problem I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676233/getapplicationcontext-returns-null-in-a-service), but I don't run the Service in another process, so it is not my case.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just calling the getApplicationContext without the context ? I run a service that uses getApplicationContext without a parent context and I never faced this kind of errors.

Comment: I cannot do this because IabHelper is an external class that doesn't extend anything, and `getApplicationContext()` is a method of `Context` (`Service` extends `Context`, so you can call the method from it)

Comment: Doesnt your service extends Service ? Because getApplicationContext is a method of Service -> http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Yes, but `getApplicationContext()` is not called from the service, but in the constructor of `IabHelper`, that does not extend `Context`. I pass the service as an argument of the constructor, from which I try to call `getApplicationContext()`, which returns `null` sometimes.